# magento editAction not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Magento Custom module saveAction is working Fine below code I used

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        if (isset($_FILES['imageurl']['name']) && $_FILES['imageurl']['name'] != '') {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('imageurl');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'Gallery'.DS;                
            $img = $path. $_FILES['imageurl']['name'];
            $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($img);
            $uploader->save($path, $filename);
            $galleryModel = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery');                
            $galleryModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                ->setDescription($postData['description'])
                ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                ->setImageurl('/Gallery/'.$filename)
                ->save();
            //var_dump($uploader);exit();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setgalleryData(false);

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setgalleryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
}
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

But Edit it's not working it's not update anything.

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $galleryId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $galleryModel  = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery')->load($galleryId);

        if ($galleryModel->getId() || $galleryId == 0) {

            Mage::register('gallery_data', $galleryModel);


            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('gallery/items');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('gallery/adminhtml_gallery_edit'))
                 ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('gallery/adminhtml_gallery_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
```

Edit Not Update Anything

Answer (score 0):

Find your updated `saveAction`

```
public function saveAction()
{

    $post_data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();


    if ($post_data) {

        try {   
         //save image
            try{

                if((bool)$post_data['imageurl']['delete']==1) {

                    $post_data['imageurl']='';

                }
                else {

                    unset($post_data['imageurl']);

                    if (isset($_FILES)){

                        if ($_FILES['imageurl']['name']) {

                            if($this->getRequest()->getParam("id")){
                                $model = Mage::getModel("gallery/gallery")->load($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
                                if($model->getData('imageurl')){
                                        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                                        $io->rm(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.implode(DS,explode('/',$model->getData('imageurl')))); 
                                }
                            }
                            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Gallery' . DS ;
                            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('imageurl');
                            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif'));
                            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                            $destFile = $path.$_FILES['imageurl']['name'];
                            $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                            $uploader->save($path, $filename);

                            $post_data['imageurl']='gallery/gallery/'.$filename;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                    return;
            }
            //save image


            $model = Mage::getModel("gallery/gallery")
            ->addData($post_data)
            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
            ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Gallery was successfully saved"));
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setGalleryData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam("back")) {
                $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
            return;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setGalleryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
        return;
        }

    }
    $this->_redirect("*/*/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks i Missed this so that it's not upload if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() && isset($_FILES['imageurl']['name']) && $_FILES['imageurl']['name'] != '') {

Comment: can you please tell me why image is not showing in edit form

Comment: Find if the image url is correct or not @Develop

Comment: No where i need to change it show direct media folder

Comment: Make sure your file path is getting save in database @Develop

Comment: No I save File name Only

Comment: `'Gallery/'.$filename` save path after media folder @Develop

Comment: Ya i am trying this only

Comment: Ya thanks it's working but Edit not update anything can you please tell me what problem in my code

Comment: if save is working then admin should work fine. Try to update using my code @Develop

Comment: Save is working My code itself if you don't mine can you please chaeck my edit function

Comment: I use default Edit i din't change anything

Comment: after edit when you save it hits to `saveAction` only @Develop

Comment: Ya First editAction , newAction , saveAction this way only i add